# How to write into a new text file and not to an old one

Tags: python

I need help on how to make my text file so that the information entered another time I run my program a new text file is created for the new information.

```
myfile = open('Entered_Driver.txt','a')
myfile.write(" Name: {0}\n Surname: {1}\n Street Address:{2}\n Car Number Plate:{3}\n".format( Name, Surname, Address, Car_Reg_Number))
myfile.close()
```

Comment: did you actually try reading the docs https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 3):

You are opening the file in append mode (`'a'`). If you want to create a new file you should use the write mode instead (`'w'`), and use another name for the file, so your previous one doesn't get deleted. To create a **different** file you can modify its name based on your data, for example naming it `Entered_Driver_xxxx` where `xxxx` is the car plate number.

Here's what you want:

```
myfile = open('Entered_Driver_' + Car_Reg_Number + '.txt','w')
myfile.write(" Name: {0}\n Surname: {1}\n Street Address:{2}\n Car Number Plate:{3}\n".format( Name, Surname, Address, Car_Reg_Number))
myfile.close()
```

For further information on `open()` see the [official documentation page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: But now when i am writing into my file, the second time all the data i entered stays but all the data i entered the first time goes away

Comment: @ParthShah I edited my answer, see if this is what you wanted.

Comment: thanks a lot was trying to find the answer for a long time

Comment: @ParthShah you're welcome! If my answer solved your question please consider marking it as correct using the green tick on the left so that new users with the same problem will benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

`myfile=open('Entered_Driver.txt','a')` Means append to the current file.

You'd want to use `'w'` instead of `'a'` to create a new file like so:

```
myfile=open('Entered_Driver.txt')
newfile=open('Name_here.txt', 'w')
newfile.write(" Name: {0}\n Surname: {1}\n Street Address:{2}\n Car Number Plate:{3}\n".format( Name, Surname, Address, Car_Reg_Number)) 
newfile.close()
myfile.close()
```

The above opens the original text file and uses `'w'` which creates/overwrites a file with the name `'Name_Here.txt'`. After that, you would just write the text into the file although it would be better to store the text to be written in a list for code shortening purposes.

Comment: But now when i am writing into my file, the second time all the data i entered stays but all the data i entered the first time goes awa